# Openlink Virtuoso exception when inserting triples

Tags: dbpedia, virtuoso

I am using the DBpedia Live mirror script.  At a certain point of the execution, it throws the following error:

> `Caused by: org.dbpedia.extraction.live.mirror.sparul.SPARULException: virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoException: COL..: Insert stopped because out of seg data here or elsewhere host 0 key RDF_QUAD_POGS s0`

I'm trying to force an integrity check by adding the following configuration parameter in `virtuoso.ini` file, with no success.

```
[Parameters]
AnalyzeFixQuadStore = 1
```

Any suggestions about what can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: [`AnalyzeFixQuadStore`](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtAnalyzeFixQuadStore) has a specific purpose, which does not appear to match this situation. I'd raise your question to [the script maintainers](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-developers) and/or the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/). (ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)

Comment: I have send the information to the dbpedia script maintainers. I'm also going to send the information to the Virtuoro Users mailing list as you suggest.